# Synch Media player with list view

Tags: android, listview, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have list view who content lyrics and   in every row i have words of the lyrics   and i have audio.mp3 that i want start and whene  it's started the list view should be move dynamicly  with the sound .
for my audio.mp3 i know how every row take in the audio with ms(millisecond) .
for example the words in the first row take 6764 ms and the second take 8120 ms.

i know there is methode who implement that i find nothing

audiopointer.xml
6764
8120
9800
10630
12060
13750
15020
16190
17368
19535
21565

Comment: please if any one have any idea

Comment: i make some researche and i find this method

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //
                }
            }, 2500);

Comment: but how can i implement this method with my listview and the time of every item

Comment: Can you show your relevant code,What you have tried?@Ali

Comment: int j=0;
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @Override
            public void run() {
          
                 myListe.setSelection(j);
             
            }  },  Integer.parseInt(namePointer.get(j))); j++;

Comment: i have in namePointer list of time (ms) for every item in my listview .but dosent work

Comment: what did you mean with approve it in my question

Comment: i checked but it still the same that i asked